# Source code of front-panel entered Altair 8800 programs

Tags: 8080, altair-8800, application-program, front-panel

I'm looking for the source code of short programs for the MITS Altair 8800 (let's say < 50 instructions to make the question more specific), so they can be entered by using only the front panel.

The best source I've found so far is http://altairclone.com/altair_experience.htm,

But there are just a few programs there for the front panel.

Does anyone know of other small programs source that can reasonably be entered in the front panel?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A single example, but a neat one: Josh's 12-byte [Microsoft 4K BASIC](https://just8bits.blogspot.com/2017/03/doing-it-in-less-than-bill-gates.html) bootloader. Kind of needs a paper tape reader and 4K BASIC, but does save your fingers from those fiddly wee switches!

Comment: I marked it as the correct answer since the question was there for some days and no further contributions were done. Thanks for the link!